# Iterate over sqlite tables in an efficient way

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a constantly expanding DB in sqlite that I need to efficiently query.
I'm looking for a way to iterate them from last to first in a memory efficient way. currently i'm using this command:

> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 2

This gives me the 2 last tables and works properly, problem is that edge cases demand of me that I look into previous tables. Any tips on how to do that properly?

Comment: Is it slow? what is your concern?

Comment: What exactly are the edge cases?

Comment: So you want more than 2 tables?

Comment: I have constantly filling tables with data, I want to fetch the 2 most recent but sometimes the data isn't there so I have to go backwards a little bit. of course I can slowly increase the LIMIT but I want to find a more elegant way of doing that.